# How to answer vb.net TCP client using netcat?

Tags: vb.net, sockets, tcp, netcat

Actually I create an connection between windows-clients and a linux server using vb.net for the client and netcat for the server.
The problem is that I cannot receive anything using `client_receive()`, because I cannot send back data from the server to the client inside the open netcat socket connection. Also I am looking for a way to not directly respond to an client - **rather time-independent**. The connection needs to keep open and the server can say anything to an connected client using e.g. `echo '$message' > /dev/tcp/client.ip/4000` in combination with `screen`. The important thing is that **it needs to be the same connection**, no new.

With the following code I am able to send strings to an port netcat is listening to:

```
 Dim stream As NetworkStream
    Dim streamw As StreamWriter
    Dim streamr As StreamReader
    Dim myclient As New TcpClient
    Dim IP As String = "example.com"
    Dim Port As Integer = 4000

Public Sub client_send(ByVal text As String)
        streamw.WriteLine(text)
        streamw.Flush()
    End Sub
    Public Function client_receive() As String
        client_receive = streamr.ReadLine
    End Function



Private Sub Welcome_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Try
            myclient.Connect(IP, Port)
            stream = myclient.GetStream
            streamw = New StreamWriter(stream)
            streamr = New StreamReader(stream)

        Catch
        End Try

End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles iamonline.Tick
        client_send("ItzMe")
        MessageBox.Show(client_receive)
    End Sub
```

We send `ItzMe` every 5 seconds to the port 4000/tcp.
In the netcat screen we see:

```
ItzMe
ItzMe
...
```

**Update #1: Changed Timer1**

**Update #2: Detailed the question**

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
while true ; do nc -l -p 4000 -c 'echo -e "message received"'; done
```

Using socat, you can create a simple echo server:

```
socat -v tcp-l:4000,fork exec:'/bin/cat'
```

Alternatively if you do not have the `-c` parameter:

```
mkfifo fifo
cat fifo  | nc -k -l 4000 -v | cat  > fifo
```

Comment: `while true; do echo -e "ur welcome!\n" | nc -k -l -p 4000 done`. Sorry I forgot to add the keepalive earlier.

Comment: Tried `while true; do echo -e "ur welcome!\n" | nc -k -l -p 4000; done`. Textbox appears two times, but the second one is empty and finally GUI freezes and netcat session get a total of 3 times `ItzMe`.

Comment: Also I am looking for a way to not directly respond to an client - rather time-independent. The connection needs to keep open and the server can say anything to the client using e.g. `screen`. Hope you understand :)

Comment: - updated the question to explain more what the goal is.

Comment: Is it possible to echo back the same message the server received? So the server would echo `ItzMe` back.

Comment: I have incorporated a echo server solution using socat or nc.